# yii2 equivalent of yii1 model()->findById() construct

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, craftcms

I am a Yii newbie, attempting to convert a Yii1-based Craft plugin to Yii2.  In the plugin, there are several uses of the following construct:

```
return MyRecord::model()->findById($id);
```

What is the equivalent Yii2 construct, specifically for the **model()->findById()** part?

Comment: `MyRecord::findOne($id)`

Comment: Thank you, that works.  I was surprised not to find this in the yii1 -> yii2 upgrade guide.  The parameters to findAll seem to have changed as well.  Am I missing a resource which lays out all these changes?   I sure couldn't find anything with Google.

Comment: Just look at the Yii2 Guide and Wiki for rest of the things.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Yii2 Guide is a real letdown for these sorts of things.  Searching on there for findById returns nothing, as does searching for my new problem method: findByAttributes.

Comment: `findById` and `findByAttributes` are from Yii1. [Yii2 ActiveRecord](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord)